# Typescript interface generics extends

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

Given the following interface:

```
interface IMyInterface<T extends { [key: string]: number }> {
    target: T;
    to:  T;
}
```

I want to change it to something like

```
interface IMyInterface<T extends { [key: string]: number }> {
    target: P extends T;
    to:  T;
}
```

where target can be any object as long as it contains the properties defined in T.

example:

```
let obj = <IMyInterface>{
    target: { name:"John", age: 100 },
    to: { age: 200 }
}
```

The typescript compiler should complain in a situation like:

```
let obj = <IMyInterface>{
    target: { name:"John", y: 1980 },
    to: { x: 20 }
}
```

where the "x" property is missing in "target"

and

```
let obj = <IMyInterface>{
    target: { name:"John", x: "20" },
    to: { x: 30 }
}
```

where the type is wrong(number vs string)

i.e. I want typechecking for the target, so that it contains all the properties defined in the "T" generics.

And I want this as an object.

Creating a method like

```
methodName<T extends { [key: string]: number }>(target: T, to: T){

}
// and calling it
methodName({ name:"John", x: "20" },{x:30});
```

i.e. with separate arguments for "target" and "to" works and the typechecking in Typescript is perfect, but I need "target" and "to" enclosed in an object so that I can have a method like:

```
methodName<IMyInterface>(object: IMyInterface){
```

and calling it like this:

```
methodName({ target: { name:"John", age:20 }, to: { age: 30}});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few first words: first, whenever you write `IMyInterface` you will need to specify the type parameter.  Something like

```
let obj = <IMyInterface> { // error
    target: { name:"John", age: 100 },
    to: { age: 200 }
}
```

will always be an error because you left out the type parameter.  This will work:

```
let obj = <IMyInterface<{ age: number }>> {
    target: { name:"John", age: 100 },
    to: { age: 200 }
}
```

Or, more idiomatically for TypeScript, you annotate the type of the variable instead of asserting the type of the value:

```
let obj: IMyInterface<{ age: number }> = {
    target: { name:"John", age: 100 },
    to: { age: 200 }
}
```

It is possible to leave out the type parameter if your definition of `IMyInterface` specifies a [default type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults), but that won't work the way you want it because the default is always the same, and you want something that changes depending on the type of the `to` property.

---

My next question would be: do you want `P` just for checking if you are correctly creating an `IMyInterface<T>`?  So once you create a valid `IMyInterface<T>` you can promptly forget about `P` when you use it?  It kind of looks like it.  In that case, what I would do is leave `P` out of the definition of `IMyInterface<T>`, and instead use a helper method.  You noted that a method could help you type check but you wanted an object, right?  Well, the helper method can *return* a valid `IMyInterface<T>`:

```
namespace HelperFunctionSolution {

  // original definition
  interface IMyInterface<T extends { [key: string]: number }> {
    target: T;
    to: T;
  }

  // helper method
  function makeMyInterface<T extends { [key: string]: number }, P extends T>(
    target: P, 
    to: T
  ): IMyInterface<T> {
    return { target, to };
  }
```

Now you can use your helper method:

```
  const goodObj = makeMyInterface({ name: "John", age: 100 }, { age: 200 }) // okay
```

If you inspect `goodObj` you will see that it's a `IMyInterface<{age: number}>`.  And the compiler complains where you'd like it to:

```
  const badObj0 = makeMyInterface({}, { x: 30 }) // x is missing
  const badObj1 = makeMyInterface({ name: "John", y: 1980 }, { x: 30 }) 
    // complains about extra property but real problem is x

  const badObj2 = makeMyInterface({ x: "20" }, { x: 30 }) // complains about string 
  const badObj3 = makeMyInterface({ name: "John", x: "20" }, { x: 30 }) 
    // complains about extra property but real problem is x
```

Now you can make the method you wanted:

```
  class Hmm {
    methodName<T extends { [key: string]: number }>(target: T, to: T) { /*impl*/ }
```

Wait, that was your definition but I think you wanted it to take an object like this:

```
    realMethodName<T extends { [key: string]: number }>(
      myInterface: IMyInterface<T>
    ) { /*impl*/ }
  }
```

And use it, *making sure to employ the helper function*:

```
  const hmm = new Hmm();
  hmm.realMethodName(makeMyInterface({ name: "John", age: 20 }, { age: 30 })); // okay

}
```

You can't use an object literal in there and guarantee type checking, since only the helper function cares about `P`.  So that is one way to do it, but you need to use the helper function.

---

Another possibility is that you carry the `P` type around with you in the `IMyInterface` definition.  This is probably not what you want, but it has the desirable effect that you can use string literals in your `methodName` method and don't need a helper function:

```
namespace TwoTypeParameterSolution {

  interface IMyInterface<T extends { [key: string]: number }, P extends T> {
    target: P;
    to: T;
  }

  class Hmm {
    realMethodName<T extends { [key: string]: number }, P extends T>(
      myInterface: IMyInterface<T,P>
    ) { /*impl*/ }
  }
  const hmm = new Hmm();
  hmm.realMethodName({target: { name: "John", age: 100 }, to: { age: 200 }}) // okay
  hmm.realMethodName({target: {}, to: { x: 30 }}) // x is missing
  hmm.realMethodName({target: { name: "John", y: 1980 }, to: { x: 30 }}) 
    // complains about extra property but real problem is x

  hmm.realMethodName({target: { x: "20" }, to: { x: 30 }}) // complains about string 
  hmm.realMethodName({target: { name: "John", x: "20" }, to: { x: 30 }}) 
    // complains about extra property but real problem is x

  hmm.realMethodName({ target: { name: "John", age: 20 }, to: { age: 30 } }); // okay
}
```

---

Either way should work for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks. this is great.
One specific example of what I need this for is for example to animate some properties of a target. 
    animate(
    { 
        target: { name:"rectangle", x: 100, y: 100, width:100,height:100}, 
        to: { x: 200, y: 200 }
    });

I want typechecking to make sure that you only animate properties that are numeric and exists on the target object.